# How to Call Internal Function From External Function in jQuery

Tags: jquery

```
$.fn.myTest=function() {
 var externalfunc=function(){
  alert('haii'); 
 }
};

$.fn.myTest.sample=function(){
 var self = this;
 self.myTest.externalfunc();
}
```

Can someone tell me how to correct this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no clue what you are trying to do here. If you extend the jQuery `.fn.` namespace, all jQuery objects inherit that propertys via prototypal inheritance.

```
jQuery.fn.myTest = function() {
   var foobar = function(){
       alert('yay');
   };
};
```

That means `$('somelement').myTest()` is now available, but you cannot access `foobar()` here since `foobar()` is a private member of `myTest()` (-> **function scope**). So is your `externalfunc()`.

You could do something like

```
jQuery.fn.myTest = function() {
   return (function(){
       alert('yay');
   }());
};
```

That now would really alert on `jQuery('element').myTest()`, but I doubt that is what you want to achieve. You always should return `this` within a `.fn.` method, to preserve the object chain.